# Can you subclass UITabBarItem and to set it with a xib file?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a custom `UITabBarItem` and to set its UI with a `xib` file like a regular `UIView`.

I've tried to create a subclass on `UITabBarItem` but the option of createing a xib file was unavailable.

Please take a look:

[image]

Is it possible to subclass `UITabBarItem` with a `xib` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarItem` inherits from `UIBarItem`, and `UIBarItem` inherits from `NSObject`.

So `UITabBarItem` is not a view object, you can't use `xib` file with it.

If you want to make some customize appearances, please read the documents of `UITabBarItem` and `UIBarItem`, in "Customizing Appearance" sections.